# Display mysql query result from a html search box in a modal, alert, or just a popup box that has closing x

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I have been working IT for 16 years and I am new to coding. I am wanting to display a search result from a input html box and have it display data from mysql database into something like a modal, alert, or a popup box that has a closing x. My database is nothing more than a word and definition. The user will type a word they want a definition for and it will display in some sort of small box that will go away when clicked.  I found some code online that when entered and then click the submit button it just shows up below the input form and stays there. Any help would be great. I feel like this should be simple but I have not been able to find anything that fits my description. Most of my findings show clicking a button  and displaying the results. If this is something simple wonderful, but if I need to upload my code I found I can. I apologize now if I am not asking properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         AJAX Search Example
      </title>
      <script>
         function fetch() {
           // GET SEARCH TERM
           var data = new FormData();
           data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
           data.append('ajax', 1);
         
           // AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open('POST', "search.php", true);
           xhr.onload = function () {
             if (this.status==200) {
               var results = JSON.parse(this.response),
                   wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
               wrapper.innerHTML = "";
               if (results.length > 0) {
                 for(var res of results) {
                   var line = document.createElement("div");
                   line.innerHTML = res['name'] + " - " + res['definition'];
                   wrapper.appendChild(line);
                 }
               } else {
                 wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found";
               }
             } else {
               alert("ERROR LOADING FILE!");
             }
           };
           xhr.send(data);
           return false;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
      <form onsubmit="return fetch();">
         <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
         <input type="text" id="search" required/>
         <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
      </form>
      <!-- [SEARCH RESULTS] -->
      <div id="results"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
// (1) DATABASE CONFIG
// ! CHANGE THESE TO YOUR OWN !
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

// (2) CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  die($ex->getMessage());
}

// (3) SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ot` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `name` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%", "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

Comment: You should add some code so we can see what you are trying.  It is extremely unlikely anyone can help you if they don't see some code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I just added the code for the index.html and search.php

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are successfully appending the child node to the document it sounds to me as though the code you're using looks a little like this...

```
var popup       = document.createElement("div");           // Create the popup container
popup.innerHTML = "<h1>Content</h1><p>Goes here....</p>";  // Add text/html inside of the container
document.body.appendChild(popup);                          // Add popup to the page
```

### Your problem

**Styling**

Pop up messages aren't created *just by adding an element to the page*. What makes it a pop up is the styling that you add to it with `CSS`.

**Removing**

To remove an element from the page you have to attach an event listener which pick up on the created element being *clicked* and then calling the `remove` method.

### Example Code

**JS**

```
// Create the element and the content
var popup       = document.createElement("div");
popup.innerHTML = "<h1>Content</h1><p>Goes here....</p>";

// Add a class for styling
popup.classList.add("popup");

// Add an onclick event listener
popup.onclick   = function(){this.remove();};

// Append the element to the document
document.body.appendChild(popup);
```

**CSS**

This sample `CSS` simply places the popup in the central area on the screen.

Note that `position: fixed;` is the line which takes the element out of the traditional linear page structure.

```
.popup{
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 15px #000;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

### Working solution

Copy/paste this into your HTML file and it should work for you. I've added plenty of comments to hopefully explain what is going on at each stage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        AJAX Search Example
    </title>
    <script>
        function fetch() {
            // Get search term from form
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
            data.append('ajax', 1);

            // Search
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    // Create the HTTP Request object
            xhr.open('POST', "search.php");    // Set connection parameters
            xhr.responseType = "json";         // Set response to JSON so that it auto parses

            // Event listener which checks status of the request and passes the response to
            // our pop up creating function
            xhr.onload = function(){        
                if(this.status == 200){
                    make_popup(this.response);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(data); // Send request
            return false;
        }

        function make_popup(response){

            // Create element and add class "popup"
            var popup = document.createElement("div");
            popup.classList.add("popup");

            // Create "close" for poup
            var close_popup = document.createElement("div");
            close_popup.innerHTML = "X";
            close_popup.classList.add("close_popup");

            // Set listener to remove the popup on click
            close_popup.onclick = function(){
                this.parentNode.remove();
            };

            // Add close to popup
            popup.appendChild(close_popup);

            /**
             * For each returned result we're going to create a new "p" element
             * which will contain the `name`, followed by a line break, and then
             * `definition` from the HTTP response the name will be in bold text.
             *
             * Markup will look like:
             *     <p> <b>NAME</b><br> DEFINTIION </p>
             * 
             */
            for(row in response){
                // Create the document elements we need
                let result  = document.createElement("p");
                let title   = document.createElement("b");
                let newline = document.createElement("br");

                // Create the text nodes for `name` and `definition`
                let title_text      = document.createTextNode(response[row].name);
                let definition_text = document.createTextNode(response[row].definition);

                // Add the elements together in the right order
                title.appendChild(title_text);
                result.appendChild(title);
                result.appendChild(newline);
                result.appendChild(definition_text);

                // Append the result to the popup
                popup.appendChild(result);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(popup);
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        .popup{
            position: fixed;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
            width: 50%;
            min-height: 50px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            border-radius: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 15px #000;
            padding: 5px 20px;
        }
        .close_popup{
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: tahoma;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 15px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            line-height: 25px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background: #000;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return fetch();">
        <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
        <input type="text" id="search" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added above the code I am using.

Comment: @ChrisThrow see additional code above. You can replace your html file with the above and it should work!